# Как присвоить переменной js цену товара

Tags: javascript

На странице выведено несколько товаров в каталоге (Woocommerce), мне нужно на этой же странице вывести по клику на "Добавить в корзину"  цену именно того товара, по чьей кнопке "Добавить в корзину" кликнуть.

Нашел два варианта кода, но первый вариант

```js
 $('.add_to_cart_button').click(function() {

var price = $('.woocommerce-Price-amount').html();
        $("#summ2").text(price + ' руб.' );
 })
```

выдает html-код первого товара на странице, а не того, по чьей кнопке был клик -

```html
<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>77.00 руб.
```

А второй вариант

```js
$('.add_to_cart_button').click(function() {

   var price = $('.woocommerce-Price-amount').text();
  
        $("#summ2").text(price + ' руб.' );
  
 })
```

**выдает** все цены товаров с этой страницы:

**£77.00£32,333.00£777.00£555.00 руб.**

**Вопрос**: как здесь вывести цену именно того товара, по чьей кнопке  "Добавить в корзину" был клик.

Всем огромное спасибо за ответ.

**update**

teran, извиняюсь за вид кода, просто спешу ответить

```html
<div class="woocommerce columns-4 "><ul class="products columns-4">

<li class="product type-product post-846 status-publish instock product_cat-osnhands shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple">
 <a href="http://wp-test.mccol.com.ua/?product=%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-2" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link"><img width="250" height="250" src="http://wp-test.mccol.com.ua/wp-content/uploads/woocommerce-placeholder-250x250.png" class="woocommerce-placeholder wp-post-image" alt="Заполнитель" srcset="" sizes="(max-width: 250px) 85vw, 250px" /><h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Оснастка ручная 2 груп</h2>
 <span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&pound;</span>777.00</span></span>
</a><a href="?add-to-cart=846" data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_id="846" data-product_sku="" aria-label="Добавить &quot;Оснастка ручная 2 груп&quot; в корзину" rel="nofollow">В корзину</a></li>
<li class="product type-product post-845 status-publish instock product_cat-osnhands shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple">
 <a href="http://wp-test.mccol.com.ua/?product=%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-1" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link"><img width="250" height="250" src="http://wp-test.mccol.com.ua/wp-content/uploads/woocommerce-placeholder-250x250.png" class="woocommerce-placeholder wp-post-image" alt="Заполнитель" srcset="" sizes="(max-width: 250px) 85vw, 250px" /><h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Оснастка ручная 1 груп</h2>
 <span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&pound;</span>555.00</span></span>
</a><a href="?add-to-cart=845" data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_id="845" data-product_sku="" aria-label="Добавить &quot;Оснастка ручная 1 груп&quot; в корзину" rel="nofollow">В корзину</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: разметку блока товара целиком приведите, чтобы ясно было как в дереве документа связаны кнопка и цена.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не менять верстку, то код будет примерно следующий:

```
$(".add_to_cart_button").click(function(){
    let price = $(this).closest('li').find(".price").text();
    $("#summ2").text( price );
});
```

вы получите результат вместе с символом фунтов. но можете либо заменить его с помощью `replace`, либо выдрать из этой строки цену с помощью регулярок.

но оптимальнее было бы изменить верстку и к самой ссылке по которой кликаете добавить атрибут `data-price` со значением цены, либо к `li`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! пробую

Comment: РАБОТАЕТ! СПАСИБО!

Answer (score 2):

```js
var list = document.querySelector('.list');

list.addEventListener('click', getPrice);

function getPrice({target}) {
  if (target.classList.contains('list__item')) {
    var price = target.dataset.price;
    target.innerText = price;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.list {
  list-style: none;
}

.list__item {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list__item" data-price="30$">get price</li>
  <li class="list__item" data-price="10$">get price</li>
  <li class="list__item" data-price="20$">get price</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: зачем писать ответ на JS если видно, что у человека код на jquery. Вставит он потом портянки ваши к себе, и будет каша очередная, как тут любят, помесь одного с другим.

Comment: Где видно? Он написал, что эти два варианта **нашел** - это первое. В тегах только js - это второе. Даже если ему нужен вариант на jq, другим людям которые когда-нибудь посетят данную страницу может понадобиться именно ванильный js(сужу по себе).

Answer (score 1):

Так попробуйте:

```
var myButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("yourButtons");
    for(var x=0; x<myButtons.length; x++) {
         myButtons[x].addEventListener("click", function() { 
            var price = this.innerHTML;
            // далее с ценой делайте что угодно
    })};
```

Comment: огромное спасибо за ответ. Но результат этого кода - 
    "В корзину руб". Цена товара не выводится...(

Answer (score 0):

огромное спасибо за ответ.

```js
var myButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("add_to_cart_button");
    for(var x=0; x<myButtons.length; x++) {
         myButtons[x].addEventListener("click", function() { 
            var price = this.innerHTML;
            // далее с ценой делайте что угодно
$("#summ2").text(price + ' руб.' );
    })};
```

Но результат этого кода -

> В корзину руб.

Цена товара не выводится...(

Comment: хватит писать говнокод смешивая нативный JS с jquery. Используйте что-то одно. `$(".add_to_cart_button").click(function(){ $("#summ2").text( $(this).text() + " руб."); })`

Comment: спасибо за совет. Но это все выводит текст, который помещен в кнопку, а нужно вывести цену товара, по чьей кнопке был клик.

Comment: это эквивалент когда из данного поста. выводит он то же самое. если хотите получить нормальный ответ, то прочитайте мой коммент к вопросу.

Comment: код вставил, посмотрите, пожалуйста