# Как сделать при нажатии на кнопку появление в ней другого текста?

Tags: html, css

Как мне сделать так:

1. Карточки должны иметь ховер эффект(без наведения, карточка должна быть черно-
   белая, использовать свойство фильтр)
2. При клике на кнопку "узнать цену", вместо надписи "узнать цену" должна появляться цена(можно сделать через ховер)

[Ссылка на codepen](https://codepen.io/andrey-orlov-the-sasster/pen/oNNOBaY)

```js
var button = $("button")


$('button').hover(
function(){
  button.html('300 P');
},
function(){
  button.html('Узнать цену');
});
```

```css
.service
  background: #f1f1f1
  max-width: 1200px
  &-block
    display: flex
    flex-wrap: wrap
    &__card 
      position: relative
      display: inline-block
      width: 300px
      height: 200px
      margin-right: 19px
      margin-bottom: 21px
      &:hover
        color: #000
      &-title
        position: absolute
        right: 0
        bottom: 10px
        font-size: 20px
        top: 42%
        left: 56%
        margin-left: -140px
        margin-top: -40px
        line-height: 28px
        color: #f2f2f2
      &-button
        position: absolute
        right: 0
        top: 48%
        left: 53%
        margin-left: -77px
        margin-top: 19px
        color: #000
        background-color: #ffc800
        padding: 8px 14px
  &__button
    margin: -25px 0 80px -30px
    font-size: 35px
  .card
    &__background
      width: 300px
      height: 200px
      transition: 0.2s
      &:hover
        filter: blur(5px)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="service">
      <!-- /.button service__button -->
      <div class="service-block">
        <div class="service-block__card">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/5jCBHQY/slide-1.jpg" alt="card" class="card__background">
          <h1 class="service-block__card-title">Монтаж систем 
            отопления</h1>
          <!-- /.service-block__title -->
          <button class="service-block__card-button button">УЗНАТЬ ЦЕНУ</button>
          <!-- /.service-block__button button -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.card -->
        <div class="service-block__card">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/tpbytBd/slide-2.jpg" alt="card" class="card__background">
          <h1 class="service-block__card-title">Здесь будет короткое описание
            о данной услуге</h1>
          <!-- /.service-block__title -->
          <button class="service-block__card-button button">УЗНАТЬ ЦЕНУ</button>
          <!-- /.service-block__button button -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.card -->
        <div class="service-block__card">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/ryBvHPx/slide-3.jpg" alt="card" class="card__background">
          <h1 class="service-block__card-title">Монтаж канализационного
            оборудования</h1>
          <!-- /.service-block__title -->
          <button class="service-block__card-button button">УЗНАТЬ ЦЕНУ</button>
          <!-- /.service-block__button button -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.card -->
        <div class="service-block__card">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/5jCBHQY/slide-1.jpg" alt="card" class="card__background">
          <h1 class="service-block__card-title">Монтаж систем 
            отопления</h1>
          <!-- /.service-block__title -->
          <button class="service-block__card-button button">УЗНАТЬ ЦЕНУ</button>
          <!-- /.service-block__button button -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.card -->
        <div class="service-block__card">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/tpbytBd/slide-2.jpg" alt="card" class="card__background">
          <h1 class="service-block__card-title">Монтаж сантехнического
            оборудования</h1>
          <!-- /.service-block__title -->
          <button class="service-block__card-button button">УЗНАТЬ ЦЕНУ</button>
          <!-- /.service-block__button button -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.card -->
        <div class="service-block__card">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/ryBvHPx/slide-3.jpg" alt="card" class="card__background">
          <h1 class="service-block__card-title">Монтаж канализационного
            оборудования</h1>
          <!-- /.service-block__title -->
          <button class="service-block__card-button button">УЗНАТЬ ЦЕНУ</button>
          <!-- /.service-block__button button -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.card -->
    </div>
      <!-- /.service-block -->
  </section>
  <!-- /.service -->
```

Comment: как вариант, написать код на javascript

Comment: да, есть такое решение, но я не знаю как довести его до ума
надо же https://jsfiddle.net/vkorotenko/bkwz2fgc/
после открытия цены за кнопкой при повторном нажатии вернуть ей первый текст, да и кнопка это не все, текст вместе с кнопкой должен менять цвет

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1047780/355286

Comment: можно попробовать сделать через `:focus`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать так. SCSS прикреплю ниже:

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.service-block__card');

[...items].forEach(item => {
  item.querySelector('.service-block__card-button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
   item.classList.toggle('service-block__card-active');
    e.target.innerText = item.classList.contains('service-block__card-active') ? '300 руб' : 'Узнать цену';
  });
});
```

```css
.service {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  max-width: 1200px;
}
.service-block {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.service-block__card {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 19px;
  margin-bottom: 21px;
  filter: grayscale(0);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: url(desaturate.svg#greyscale);
  filter: gray;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(0);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(0);
  -o-filter: grayscale(0);
}
.service-block__card-active .service-block__card-button {
  color: red;
}
.service-block__card:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
}
.service-block__card-title {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  top: 42%;
  left: 56%;
  margin-left: -140px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #f2f2f2;
}
.service-block__card-button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 48%;
  left: 53%;
  margin-left: -77px;
  margin-top: 19px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #ffc800;
  padding: 8px 14px;
}
.service__button {
  margin: -25px 0 80px -30px;
  font-size: 35px;
}
.service .card__background {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<section class="service">
      <!-- /.button service__button -->
      <div class="service-block">
        <div class="service-block__card">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/5jCBHQY/slide-1.jpg" alt="card" class="card__background">
          <h1 class="service-block__card-title">Монтаж систем 
            отопления</h1>
          <!-- /.service-block__title -->
          <button class="service-block__card-button button">УЗНАТЬ ЦЕНУ</button>
          <!-- /.service-block__button button -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.card -->
        <div class="service-block__card">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/tpbytBd/slide-2.jpg" alt="card" class="card__background">
          <h1 class="service-block__card-title">Здесь будет короткое описание
            о данной услуге</h1>
          <!-- /.service-block__title -->
          <button class="service-block__card-button button">УЗНАТЬ ЦЕНУ</button>
          <!-- /.service-block__button button -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.card -->
        <div class="service-block__card">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/ryBvHPx/slide-3.jpg" alt="card" class="card__background">
          <h1 class="service-block__card-title">Монтаж канализационного
            оборудования</h1>
          <!-- /.service-block__title -->
          <button class="service-block__card-button button">УЗНАТЬ ЦЕНУ</button>
          <!-- /.service-block__button button -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.card -->
        <div class="service-block__card">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/5jCBHQY/slide-1.jpg" alt="card" class="card__background">
          <h1 class="service-block__card-title">Монтаж систем 
            отопления</h1>
          <!-- /.service-block__title -->
          <button class="service-block__card-button button">УЗНАТЬ ЦЕНУ</button>
          <!-- /.service-block__button button -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.card -->
        <div class="service-block__card">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/tpbytBd/slide-2.jpg" alt="card" class="card__background">
          <h1 class="service-block__card-title">Монтаж сантехнического
            оборудования</h1>
          <!-- /.service-block__title -->
          <button class="service-block__card-button button">УЗНАТЬ ЦЕНУ</button>
          <!-- /.service-block__button button -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.card -->
        <div class="service-block__card">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/ryBvHPx/slide-3.jpg" alt="card" class="card__background">
          <h1 class="service-block__card-title">Монтаж канализационного
            оборудования</h1>
          <!-- /.service-block__title -->
          <button class="service-block__card-button button">УЗНАТЬ ЦЕНУ</button>
          <!-- /.service-block__button button -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.card -->
    </div>
      <!-- /.service-block -->
  </section>
  <!-- /.service -->
```

```css
.service
  background: #f1f1f1
  max-width: 1200px
  &-block
    display: flex
    flex-wrap: wrap
    &__card 
      &-active
        & .service-block__card-button
          color: red
      position: relative
      display: inline-block
      width: 300px
      height: 200px
      margin-right: 19px
      margin-bottom: 21px
      filter: grayscale(0)
      -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%)
      -moz-filter: grayscale(100%)
      -ms-filter: grayscale(100%)
      -o-filter: grayscale(100%)
      filter: url(desaturate.svg#greyscale)
      filter: gray
      -webkit-filter: grayscale(1)
      &:hover
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(0)
      -moz-filter: grayscale(0)
      -ms-filter: grayscale(0)
      -o-filter: grayscale(0)
      
      &-title
        position: absolute
        right: 0
        bottom: 10px
        font-size: 20px
        top: 42%
        left: 56%
        margin-left: -140px
        margin-top: -40px
        line-height: 28px
        color: #f2f2f2
      &-button
        position: absolute
        right: 0
        top: 48%
        left: 53%
        margin-left: -77px
        margin-top: 19px
        color: #000
        background-color: #ffc800
        padding: 8px 14px
  &__button
    margin: -25px 0 80px -30px
    font-size: 35px
  .card
    &__background
      width: 300px
      height: 200px
      transition: 0.2s
```